# Import file structure and collection publish

Tags: meteor

Following Meteor docs on how to use the import directory structure, [Example directory layout](https://guide.meteor.com/v1.3/structure.html#example-app-structure).

```
//-------------- publication.js`
import {Vehicles} from '../vehicles.js';
 Meteor.publish('vehicles', function () {
    return Vehicles.find();
});

//-------------- carClass.jsx
import './vehicles/server/publications.js';
const composer = (props, onData) => {
  const subscription = Meteor.subscribe('vehicles');

  if (subscription.ready()) {
    const vehicle = Vehicles.findOne({name: 'jack'});
    onData(null, { vehicle });
  }
};
```

Does the publish method need to be exported?
Error in browser console saying:

> Uncaught Error: Cannot find module './vehicles/server/publications.js'

How can this error be fixed?  Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meteor publications are server-only code, so you can't import that script in carClass.jsx.

You should have some file like {app root}/server/main.js. You import your publications here to make them available for client scripts to subscribe to. It's important that this file isn't inside of the /imports folder, so that it is eagerly loaded when the server starts.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the path `./vehicles/server/publications.js` is not reachable from the `carClass.jsx` file. You should reference it by `./server/publications.js`

Comment: That gives the error Uncaught Error: Cannot find module './server/publications.js'

Comment: Does your IDE support navigating through files using a code completion scheme? I mean, can you type import './' and then it shows where you can go from there? Because it seems it cannot find the module in the specified path. Then, the path I have showed before seems correct from me in the snapshot you have provided.

Comment: Yes. I am using Webstorm and it is happy with my first selection which I posted but not the selection stated in your answer. i.e. the code completion scheme shows my selection but not yours as I am typing them.